# Access Xcom in EmailOperator of Airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jinja2, airflow

I'm very new to Airflow and I'm facing some problems with Xcom and Jinja.

I have to do some Python elaborations and then pass the result to an EmailOperator in order to send it as the email body.

Seems that does not exist documentation about it, the only hint that I've found is this [link](https://www.developintelligence.com/blog/2017/02/using-airflow-manage-devops-etls/) and it is badly formed, doesn't work and it's badly commented.
I think that it has to be done via Jinja, but I'm not getting how...

This is the tentative I'm working on, could someone please help me and explain me why this code is wrong and how to fix it?

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 11, 7),
    'email': ['ciccio.pasticcio@noreply.it'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    'dg_daily_saint',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='10 9 * * *')

task1 = PythonOperator(task_id="extract_daily_saint",
                                     python_callable=extractDailySaint,
                                     provide_context=True,
                                     dag=dag)


def html_output(**context):
    value=context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='extract_daily_saint', key='saint')
    return "<h1>" + value + "</h1>"


EMAIL_CONTENT = """
    <b> {{ html_output(context) }}</b>
    """

mail = EmailOperator(
    task_id='mail',
    to='ciccio.pasticcio@noreply.it',
    subject='DataGovernance',
    html_content=EMAIL_CONTENT,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)

task1 >> mail
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is not working? What error are you seeing?

Comment: On which part of the code you are having a problem ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers!
The problem is related to the rendering of the EMAIL_CONTENT variable.
I don't know the correct way to use an Xcom value outside an operator.

My DAG stucks in running state on the email task for minutes and then I receive a timeout error.
If I remove the jinja part and use a static text inside EMAIL_CONTENT it works properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Being stuck might be another issue but I see a little confusion about pusher and puller.

Pusher is the operator that push a parameter to another operator. Pusher needs `xcom_push=True`. For `PythonOperator`, a returned value will be pushed.

Puller is the operator receives the parameter from the pusher. Puller needs `provide_context=True`

Thus, in your example

```
task1 = PythonOperator(task_id="extract_daily_saint",
                       python_callable=extractDailySaint,
                       xcom_push=True,  # not provide_context
                       dag=dag)
```

Then in your puller, you can use macros directly in Jinja template.

```
mail = EmailOperator(
    task_id='mail',
    to='ciccio.pasticcio@noreply.it',
    subject='DataGovernance',
    html_content="<b><h1> {{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='extract_daily_saint') }} </h1></b>",
    provide_context=True,  # puller needs provide_context
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: Thank you, now it is clearer how to use pusher and puller!